# Is it possible to integrate Tableau in Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, tableau-api

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04 and as it is known Ubuntu does not support Tableau. I was just wondering if it is possible to somehow integrate Tableau and Python so as to run Tableau within Python.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the following:

[Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/11/leverage-power-python-tableau-tabpy-62077) and [Tableau Community](https://community.tableau.com/thread/236479). Also, make sure you follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) when asking questions. That's the reason your question was down voted.